# find process that's generating CAL interrupts (syscalls)

Tags: linux, kernel, performance, administration

I have a peak of CAL type interrupts, 20,000 per second. How do I find the process that's generating them on SUSE11?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could easily determine that with SystemTap

It's a dynamic probing system, similar to Dtrace in Solaris that allows you to inspect
the kernel and applications syscalls.

Here's how to install it in SLES 11:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/topic/liaai/systemTap/liaaisystapsuse.htm